# How to to stop accepting input once the user presses ENTER? C programming language

Tags: arrays, c, character

I'm a first year CS student and I tried writing code from a given prompt. This is the prompt:

Write a program that:

1. creates char array array_1 of length 10.
2. creates char array array_2 of length 10, and
3. stop receiving input into array_1 and array_2 when the user hits ENTER and
4. insert a null character into the array.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char array_1[10];
    
    printf("Enter a character in array_1 (Press ENTER to stop):\n");
    
    do { 
        scanf("%c", &array_1[10]); 
    } 
    while(array_1[10] != '\n'); 
    
    printf("\\0 \n");
    
    char array_2[10];

    printf("Enter a character in array_2 (Press ENTER to stop):\n");

    do { 
        scanf("%c", &array_1[10]); 
    } 
    while(array_1[10]!='\n'); 
    
    printf("\\0 \n"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&array_1[10]` is a pointer to the *eleventh* element of the ten-element array.

Comment: You also seem to have a simple copy-paste error.

Comment: And perhaps what you really should use is [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead? It will solve both your out-of-bounds problem and also read newline-delimited input.

Comment: The task description is unclear. How should your program behave if the user enters more than 10 characters in one line, although you only have room for 10? Are you allowed to rely on the user not entering too many characters?

Comment: The task description states that you should write a terminating null character into the array(s). It does not tell you to print a terminating null character to standard output (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You're right. It says I should insert a null character into array_1 and array_2 but I honestly didn't know how should I insert a null character into the array. I just used printf to "insert" it into the array after the user presses ENTER as an alternative. As for the behavior of the program, the prof didn't really specify anything in particular. I wanted to add an if...else statement regarding the number of characters, but was not sure of where do I put it. If you have any advice, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)s' comment. a better approach to your problem would definitely be using fgets() instead of scanf().
Here's an updated solution to your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char array_1[10];

    printf("Enter a character in array_1 (Press ENTER to stop):\n");
    //Replacing the whole do while loop
    fgets(array_1, sizeof array_1, stdin);

    printf("\\0 \n");

    char array_2[10];

    printf("Enter a character in array_2 (Press ENTER to stop):\n");

    //Replacing the whole do while loop
    fgets(array_2, sizeof array_2, stdin);

    printf("\\0 \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the [community guidelines on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471), I will not provide a full solution to the problem, but I will provide the following:

You are writing every character that you read from standard input to `array_1[10]`. Since array indexes are zero-based, you are always writing to the 11<sup>th</sup> element of the array, which does not even exist, as the array has a size of 10.

You should instead write the first character to the first element of the array, which is `array_1[0]`, then, if the first character is not a newline character, write the second character to the second element of the array, which is `array_1[1]`, etc. This can be accomplished with a `for` loop using a loop counter variable, for example like this:

```
int i;

//Limiting the loop to 9 iterations will prevent a buffer overflow.
//We are not doing 10 iterations, because the buffer only has space
//for 9 characters (10 characters if you include the terminating
//null character).
for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
    //attempt to read next character and break loop prematurely if
    //an error occurs
    if ( scanf("%c", &array_1[i]) != 1 )
        break;

    //break loop prematurely if user entered newline character
    if ( array_1[i] == '\n' )
    {
        //the following line is necessary unless you want the
        //newline character to be overwritten by the terminating
        //null character, which effectively discards the newline
        //character (this may be desirable)
        i++;

        break;
    }
}

//add terminating null character
array_1[i] = '\0';
```